# Angular JS - $scope.$appy - Instant Update Select Options HTML with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a graph drawing project. When I add a new graph, the variable "data" is updating.

In the beginning, "data" variable is null.

```
var data = {
  "nodes": [],
  "edges": []
};
```

Then, it changes by adding new edges or nodes to graph.

```
var data = {
  "nodes": [{id:5,label:"a"}],
  "edges": []
};
```

> I want to make a "instant update select->options". If add new edge or
>   nodes the option list should be updated.

When html page created, the list is empty, however after I update the variable, list is still empty. I checked about `$scope.$apply` however I could not find a solution for my issue.

I am looking forward for your help. Thank you very much.

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control" id="node-equivalent">
  <option ng-repeat="n in data.nodes">{{n.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `$scope.$apply()` by injecting scope into controller, so that the whole digest cycle will be ran again and update the variables.

```
   `this` will also work in your case.
```

Check this out

```
  var vm = this;
            vm.data = {
              "nodes": [],
              "edges": []
                      };

            $timeout(function () {
                vm.data = {
  "nodes": [{id:5,label:"a"}],
  "edges": []
}
            }, 2000);

        })
```

I have added `timeout` fn for refresh on every `2secs`

Comment: Thank you, it works for me when I use $interval, instead of $timeout.

Comment: @TeodorAk,Mark it as up. If this answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a `$scope` variable. Hence two-way binding not working. Please refer to Angular docs for better understanding.

It should be:

```
$scope.data = {
"nodes": [{id:5,label:"a"}],
"edges": []
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.